# Problems generating barcode with ruby

Tags: ruby, barcode

I am trying to generate barcodes in ruby and tried a couple of gems: 
[barcode-generator](https://github.com/anujluthra/barcode-generator) and [rghost_barcode](https://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost-barcode/wiki/).

These gems, generate the barcodes just fine but in an image format.  Now, when we print out this barcode with some special printer, like the 'zebra z4m plus', the scanner doesn't recognize this barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, your problem is to generate code to drive your printer rather than generating a pixel graphic with your barcode.

The "language" of your printer is [ZPL or ZPLII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_%28programming_language%29).

There is a Ruby gem supposedly doing that: [zebra_zpl](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/zebra_zpl). No ideas if it works.

For an alternative approach, see also [How to print (barcode) labels from a Ruby on Rails Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5574754/908515). This means basically creating the ZPL code yourself.

Comment: Thank you.Now I write code to generate ZPLII code then use [jzebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) to print the barcode.

Comment: @oscar: Thank you for the hint. The question was not about generating a PDF but about driving a certain printer (zebra z4m plus). Please note that the question specifically mentions rghost_barcode was tried.